Name the Jackie Chan movie which involves a ring that after wearing it made people disappear
In this movie Jackie chan and his friends try to fool one of their friends by giving him a fake ring? The friend eventually tries to spy the main actress bathing, but is caught by surprise that the ring was fake. I tried to it google it but could not find it. Any help will be appreciated. If possible could someone show a link to this movie.

That sounds like a Peter Jackson movie to me ...

Can you comment on when/where you saw it, and in what year/decade you think the movie was released?

@MattD: I think it was released sometime between 1990's

I believe this to be the Hong Kong release called "Winners and Sinners", which is a comedy about some ex cons attempting to go straight, but getting caught up with a local crime boss anyway.
I couldn't find any reference to a ring, but I did find this excerpt from the book "Dying for Action: The Life and Films of Jackie Chan", which states:

Note: Some versions are missing a lengthy sequence in which Richard Ng works on mentally making himself invisible so that he can watch a girl taking a bath.

To get to it, click on the first box of the search result with Richard Ng's name highlighted and scroll down a page or so.
Click here for trailer

Indeed there is no ring involved, it is that i watched this movie 21 years ago forgot the actual scenes slightly. Anyways thanks for the correction. This sight has very knowledgeable people. I thought it was impossible to get a hold of this movie and lost hope but thanks @johnP: appreciate your help.
